# how to format string to show two decimal places

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am facing a slight issue when trying to get two decimal places after pasring double to string and trying to format

```
  pieChart.setCenterText("$" + "" + ""  +String.format( "% 1$ .2f", Double.toString(dataCost),""));
```

can  anyone help me improve the above line of code so that it can display to two decimal places? You will also notice that I am trying to leave a space between the dollar sign and the value

Comment: What is the Problem with your code? What is the Output and what do you expected?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `String.format("%.2f", d)` , your double will be rounded automatically

```
pieChart.setCenterText("$ " + String.format("%.2f", d));
```

Comment: mdDroid thanks this one works without causing the app to crash

Comment: @Zidane always welcome

Comment: double totalDistance = distance(Double.parseDouble(prefs.getString("last_lat", null)), Double.parseDouble(prefs.getString("last_lang", null)), location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            Log.d("Distance====>", String.format("%.2f", totalDistance));

Answer (score 5):

Following code might help you

```
double a = 1.234567;
double a = 2;
NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
System.out.println(nf.format(a));
System.out.println(nf.format(a));
```

and the output will be

```
1.23
2
```

it only show decimal places if needed, Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This

```
 pieChart.setCenterText("$ " + String.format("%.2f", dataCost));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DecimalFormat.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat; 
DecimalFormat money = new DecimalFormat ("$0.00");
System.out.println(money.format(dataCost));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    float val = 1245.235645f;
    double ans = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(val));

    System.out.println(ans);
```

> Note : ##.## means 2 digits will be displayed after the .(dot)

```
Package  : import java.text.DecimalFormat;
```

this should helps you.